# Can I resolve random effect (individual difference) problem with z-score?

Tags: random-effects-model, z-score

In group-level analysis, I learned that stochastic effect can be generated by two source: measurement noise & individual difference.

For example, because fMRI signal might be different because of not only noise during fMRI's mechanical process but also variability in individual's cerebrovascular structure, it would be impossible to widen result to unobserved person, if we did not consider individual difference.

General way to address the problem would be two-level approach, in which we calculate within-subject feature (e.g. linear regression coefficient between activity of hippocampus and task performance across trials for each subject) and, then, summarize them in group-level analysis (e.g. whether individuals' linear trend are significantly lower than average of that of control subjects or not).

In this regards, my question is that is it make sense that to normalize (z-score) both activity of hippocampus and task performance separately for each individual and, then, to calculate significance of linear trend between "all-subjects merged" normalized activity of hippocampus and task performances?

In other words, can I believe that although the approach did not directly address random effect from individual person, it resolved the effect because it standardized the values to remove individual variability?